# PhpStorm not connecting to Docker container Xdebug

Tags: php, docker, phpstorm, xdebug

I am currently really struggling with PhpStorm, Docker and Xdebug to get them working together.

I installed Xdebug in a PHP container with the following Dockerfile and yaml file, which are exactly the same on the following website: https://blog.philipphauer.de/debug-php-docker-container-idea-phpstorm/.

After correctly verifying the configuration in PhpStorm (see screenshot), I started the Debug Session in PhpStorm. After using the Xdebug helper in Chrome, I started a new request. Although everything looks fine, PhpStorm does not stop on the breakpoints.

I really do not know where the problem occurs. Trying to log did not help and setting a remote IP or just the connect_back option in xdebug did not solve the problem.

Thanks for your help!

```
FROM php:7.0.19-apache

RUN apt-get update &&\
apt-get install --no-install-recommends --assume-yes --quiet ca-certificates curl git &&\
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN pecl install xdebug-2.5.5 && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug
RUN echo 'zend_extension="/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012/xdebug.so"' >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
RUN echo 'xdebug.remote_port=9000' >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
RUN echo 'xdebug.remote_enable=1' >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
RUN echo 'xdebug.remote_connect_back=1' >> /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini

version: '2'
services:
  apache_with_php:
    build: .
volumes:
  - ./src:/var/www/html/
ports:
  - "80:80"
```

[image: Test succeeded]

Comment: *"PhpStorm not connecting to Docker container Xdebug"* PhpStorm does not need to connect anywhere -- it's Xdebug that needs to connect to PhpStorm. If it's unable to connect -- very often it will be the firewall issue (or xdebug port is occupied by another service and therefore PhpStorm is unable to listen on it; especially on Mac) or wrong IP address for `xdebug.remote_host` (and `xdebug.remote_connect_back=1` fails to detect the right IP). It may also be Docker issue (especially on Mac). What xdebug log has to say (`xdebug.remote_log`)?

Comment: Hey mate, let me know if you still need help with this, I got it working myself a few months ago. @iphoneintosh

Comment: I am experiencing this issue.

PhpStorm verifies the xdebug set up.  A look at the output of phpinfo shows all the settings are correct, yet none of the breakpoints fire.  I do not even get the expecting pop up asking to accept connections or any of the initial mapping queries I would expect if xdebug was sending data back to the IDE.